# Isolate a column of a vector in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I have a 2d vector of string and need to isolate out three of the columns into 3 separate 1d arrays so i can convert them to doubles and perform operations on them.

Simply using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            vectorname[i][2] = arrayname[i];
        }
```

doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Sorry im new to coding and thanks in advance.

Thanks to first reply, i don't care if i remove the data or not, i just need it so i can operate on it, my vectors are declared as:

```
string vectorname[101][5];


string arrayname[99];
string arrayname2[99];
string arrayname3[99];
```

Ok I dont have my vectorname defined as a vector, it's just a 2d string, can i extract a column from that?

Comment: Please edit your post with the definition of `vectorname`.  Don't describe, show.

Comment: "doesn't work and I don't understand why." Clearly you're getting some error or wrong result. Could you show us?

Comment: Why are you allocating your subarrays as only 99 elements, when `vectorname` has a first dimension of 101?

Comment: Why do you want to isolate those columns into separate arrays? How are you planning on using those new arrays? You could just reference the column in the original...

Answer (score 0):

Do the columns still need to remain in the 2D vector, or be pulled out completely as independent data?

If you need independent data, I would do

```
vector<double> col(vectorname[i]);
```

Then manipulate col as needed. You could even do move construction if you don't need that data in the 2D vector anymore.

I think you have actual logic problems elsewhere though. Show us your vector declarations.

**EDIT:** What...? You're not declaring vectors at all. You're using pure arrays. And a 2D array shouldn't be called a vector. You're confusing other programmers with your name scheme.

The proper way to declare a vector of strings is

```
std::vector<string> vectorname(100);
```

And a vector of vector of strings (a 2D vector) is

```
std::vector<std::vector<string>(5)> vectorname(101);
```

But moreover, your dimensions mismatch. Your 1D vectors need to be the same length as the given dimension of your 2D, or 5 (101?) in this case.

If you're trying to copy the values along the first dimension of values, there's no direct constructor for that. You have to manually loop from 0 to 100 and say

```
arrayname[i] = vectorname[i][n];
```

Where n is your column number.

Comment: thanks, i've edited the question to hope to give you an answer.

Comment: You're a Fortran programmer, aren't you... You're swapping the canonical row-column order for c++. Generally for c++ you think in row-column-strut order or x-y-z order if that makes more sense to you.

Comment: sorry i should of specified, the reason the numbers don't match is because I've already removed headers from the columns.

Comment: So are you copying 100(ish) values along the first dimension, or 5 along the second? You can't do the former directly, because C++ is row-major order. You have to use a loop, because vector[i][0]...vector[i][4] are in memory continuously before vector[i+1][0] is reached. The latter is much easier.